# Is it a good practice to use getter to render another component inside React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getter, react-component

In some cases, the getter methods become handy. But what about using a getter method to render React component or whole DOM? Isn't it better to use classic method instead of a getter for this purpose? And why exactly?

I have a feeling that something is not OK on this, but also I know that this stuff can be about an author's feeling.

So the question is if this a good way in general? Or what are your preferences?

```
class Attachment extends React.Component {

  get file() {
    return this.props.fields.File;
  }
  get label() {
    return this.props.fields.Label;
  }

  // I'm asking about these 2 getters below this comment

  get editableAttachment() {
    return <SomeComponent field={this.label} />;
  }

  get attachment() {
    return (
      <a
        href={this.file && this.file.value && this.file.value.src}
        target="_blank"
      >
        {(this.label && this.label.value)}
      </a>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ui-some-component">
        {this.props.isPageEditing ? this.editableAttachment : this.attachment}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Or what are your preferences?" you stated. Well the answer is: it is up to your own preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very much to the taste of the consumer, I believe that if you don't introduce barbarities any code is good.

It's also true that the more understandable the code, the better. I'd try to make the code as simple and legible as possible for the person who doesn't know my code.

On the other hand, I try to make the components as simple and presentational as possible.

Maybe this would be an example of your own code using "my style guide":

```
const Attachment = ({ isPageEditing, fields }) => {
  const { file, label } = fields;

  const attachment = isPageEditing ? (
    <SomeComponent field={fields.label} />
  ) : (
    <a href={file && file.value && file.value.src} target="_blank">
      {label && label.value}
    </a>
  );

  return <div className="ui-some-component">{attachment}</div>;
};
```

I hope I helped you,
Best

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes down to preference. You won't have any gains by deferring the calculation compared to a more basic `if x do this, if y do that` render -- both have to do the work.

My two cents is to keep the component simple and readable. Jumping around a class for every condition makes it more difficult for the next developer.